# How to search fulltext within Outlook XP attachments (pdf files) in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook, search

I need to do a full text search on the email database of `Outlook XP` on a PC with `Windows XP SP3` which also searches within attached files like `PDF` files.

Using Windows search did not find anything (although I know that at least one attached PDF does contain the searched word, but I need to find others which contain it as well).

Using the search in Outlook with the Lookout Plugin also did not find the corresponding e-mail neither.

What can I do to find what I'm searching for?

Comment: You could try FileLocator Pro. It has a 30-day trial period so you can use it for free then delete it after you've finished your search project: http://help.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorpro/en/index.html?outlook_pst_archive_searching.htm

Comment: Dump it all the Gmail and you can get results in less than a second.

Comment: @sunk818 And enjoy spooky targeted advertising for the rest of your life whenever you use google.

Comment: why the downvote? I'll gladly improve the question, if I knew what's "wrong" with it. Please comment

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I take you've never heard of an ad blocker? What ads? I haven't seen ads in Gmail for years now.

Comment: @sunk818 Lucky you - you never had to use someone else's or public / corporate computer =)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Windows Desktop Search](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/917013)? It's free and surprisingly not bloated for a Microsoft product.

Comment: thanks for this hint! NO, currently I use LookOut and UltraSearch, but I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

[Copernic Desktop Search free version](http://www.copernic.com/en/products/desktop-search/) is a good software for indexing your e-mail and attachments. Although it can be a resource hog, it does work. To find PDF, the document has to be OCRed and requires a text layer. Assuming your PDF has text layer, Copernic Desktop Search will find it. Alternatively, Google Drive will automatically OCR the first ten pages with any PDF you upload. Search is extremely fast as well.